# List/Dump table description with mysql on linux?

Tags: linux, mysql

I have 2 dozen tables in a mysql DB. I can see the table by using desc tableName; How i dump the desc for all tables into a file so i can look through them easily and quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqldump with --no-data will dump the schema out for you, e.g.:

```
mysqldump --opt --no-data -h $host-u $username -p$password $database
```